How do you create a very large sparse array in Windows?
From What they don’t tell you about demand paging in school they demonstrate how to create a sparse array with mmap. With this code, I can easily create an extremely large sparse array, say 1TB in size, despite only having 32GB of ram available. The advantage here is that only pages I write to will be backed by physical memory, and any other page can safely be read from and will simply return zeros.
Is it possible to achieve this exact same behavior on Windows?
EDIT: First I tried VirtualAlloc, but reserving a large array without committing seems to throw memory access violaiton upon read instead of simply returning zero. If I commit, then the storage gets (or attempts to get) backing as soon as I read from it. Next I tried CreateFileMapping + MapViewOfFile but this is using up lots of temporary space on my filesystem, and I can't manage to get an array much larger than 50GB on my computer. I'm hoping I'm just not using these functions correctly, or perhaps there's another option that actually replicates what I have in Linux.
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>

const size_t MB = 1024 * 1024;
const size_t GB = MB * 1024;

int main() {
  size_t alloc_size = 512 * MB;
  size_t total_alloc = 100 * GB;
  size_t num_allocs = total_alloc / alloc_size;

  std::cout << "Allocating mem...\n";

  char* base = nullptr;

  // Allocate a ton of memory
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_allocs; i++) {
    // Unsound alert - assuming allocations are contiguous and grow down.
    base = (char*)mmap(NULL, alloc_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (base == MAP_FAILED) {
      perror(NULL);
      throw std::runtime_error("Fail");
    }
    std::cout << (void*)base << " " << i << "\n";
  }

  std::cout << "Allocated Virtual Mem (GB): " << total_alloc / GB << "\n";
  std::cout << "Base Addr: " << (void*)base << "\n";
  std::cout << "Press enter to start reading.\n";
  getchar();
  std::cout << "Reading each page...\n";

  // Read the first byte of each page
  for (size_t i = 0; i < total_alloc; i += 0x1000) {
    auto x = base[i];
  }

  std::cout << "Done!\n";
  getchar();
}


I don't think this is possible on windows. Windows doesn't allow overcommitment of memory in the same way that that linux does. This is why windows doesn't have an OOM killer - it swaps one type of memory error for another. Windows refuses to commit to more than RAM + swap (page file). See https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available for more details.

Also, be careful about your read loop. Looks like the sort of thing that a compiler would easily optimize away.

@Dunes I was hoping this was not the case. Utilizing cpu page table hardware to handle sparse datasets seems like a very simple and efficient way of handling things.

Will Microsoft Windows 10 overcommit memory?, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment, MemoryError on Windows but not MacOS when using np.zeros

This question is similar to: MemoryError on Windows but not MacOS when using np.zeros. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does Windows have sparse files?  Can you create a large sparse file (occupying no actual disk space) and then map it?
